# Bundling and minifying options for MVC2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css

I've just been handed an MVC2 application and noticed that there is no bundling or minifying of the JavaScript or Stylesheets. I've used the built in bundling and minifying logic that comes out the box with MVC3+ but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be available with MVC2.

I am unable to upgrade the project to a later version so my question is as follows...

What are my options for bundling and minifying within an MVC2 application?

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat I've updated. I'm not after software recommendations just some options, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually minify and bundle the files and add some compilation instructions to switch between the two options depending on whether you are building for release or debug

If its your own javascript/css and it changes often you can automatic the minify process into your build script.